# Read Timed out error in calling a Rest API

Tags: community, callout

Getting timedout error when calling a rest api.

Already set maximum value for timeout.

```
req.setTimeout(120000);
```

Also implemented retry for 3 times by catching the exception.

Error occurs for only few calls to rest api, though the body is same for every call.

Answer (score 1):

The 120,000ms limit applies to all callouts in the same transaction. That means if the first call timed out at 120,000ms, you won't [have any more time left](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) for a retry that transaction. You would have to somehow chain to a new transaction to try again. What this means depends on the context you're currently working in.

> Maximum cumulative timeout for all callouts (HTTP requests or Web services calls) in a transaction
>
> 120 seconds

Comment: Might be a good use of a system event to get yourself a new context